# How do I add an attribute to a rails select dropdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Okay, so I'm trying my hand at some ajax in rails and have hit a massive brick wall: I can't set the `data-remote` attribute in my select box. No matter what form I try it in, it always acts as if the parts telling it about that attribute aren't even there. Example:

```
<%= f.select(:image, options_from_collection_for_select(@images, 'id', 'name'), data: {remote: true}) %>
<%= f.select( [...] , :'data-remote' => 'true') %>
<%= f.select( [...] , :data => {remote: true}) %>
<%= f.select( [...] , data: {remote: true}) %>
<%= f.select( [...] , remote: true) %>
```

I even have working code that implements the first three on other things, but just not that `f.select`

So does anybody know how I can properly apply an attribute to an `f.select`?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `select` at [http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` key needs to be in an HTML options hash which is the third argument to `select`. From the documentation:

```
select(method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Therefor you need:

```
f.select(:image, options_from_collection_for_select(@images, 'id', 'name'), {}, { data: {remote: true} })
```

Note the empty options hash.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that the html options were in a different area. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= f.select :image, options_for_select(@images.map{ |i| [i.name, i.id, {'data-remote'=>true}] }) %>
```